# Сменить раскладку на противоположную

Tags: php

Никак не пойму, как сменить раскладку текста - не на "правильную" - просто на противоположную. Делаю так, но всегда раскладка остается русской:

```
function textSwitch($text) {
        $search = [
            'й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
            'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
            'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю',
            'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
            'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','\'',
            'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.'
        ];

        $rep = [
            'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
            'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','\'',
            'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.',
            'й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
            'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
            'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю',
        ];

        return str_replace($search, $rep, $text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое решение могу предложить:

```
function textSwitch($text) {
        $search = [
            'й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
            'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
            'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю',
            'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
            'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','\'',
            'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.'
        ];

        $rep = [
            'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']',
            'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','\'',
            'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.',
            'й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ',
            'ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э',
            'я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю',
        ];

        $newArr = array_combine($search, $rep);
        return strtr($text, $newArr);
    }
```